# Why instapy cannot find element xpath

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, instapy

I executed this code for a testing robot and I got this error and I don't know what i have to do?

```
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username="<your_username>", password="<your_password>")
session.login()
session.like_by_tags(["bmw", "mercedes"], amount=5)
session.set_dont_like(["naked", "nsfw"])
session.set_do_follow(True, percentage=50)
session.set_do_comment(True, percentage=50)
session.set_comments(["Nice!", "Sweet!", "Beautiful :heart_eyes:"])
session.end()
```

Error:

```
File "c:/Users/omid/Desktop/New folder/instaPy.py", line 4, in <module>
    session.login()
  File "C:\Users\omid\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\instapy\instapy.py", line 366, in login
    if not login_user(self.browser,
  File "C:\Users\omid\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\instapy\login_util.py", line 203, in login_user
    login_elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
  File "C:\Users\omid\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\omid\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\omid\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\omid\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in 
check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//article//a[text()='Log in']"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.66)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18363 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.44*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.44*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v69-71**

- You are using *chrome=87.0.4280.66*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v87.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 87**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.44* and the *Chrome Browser v85.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v87.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 87.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v87.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/notes.txt)).
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.